# How to update IAM Policy using Boto3 Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a S3 bucket read policy :

```
   {
      "Version":"2012-10-17",
      "Statement":[
        {
          "Effect":"Allow",
          "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
          "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Based on a cloud trail logs when new bucket is created , I am creating an event which will invoke a Lambda function.

Able to read json for the policy and add a new resource (bucket) to the same policy. Is there a direct python API to be invoked which will update an existing IAM policy with new resource ?

Comment: No, you need to replace the policy. Of course you could do that by loading the current policy into some kind of JSON-aware code, insert the things that are currently missing, emit the updated policy as a string, and then update the S3 policy with that. By the way that's an S3 policy you've shown, not an IAM policy - they look similar but are different (it has a Principal).

Comment: An alternative is to have a bucket naming scheme (eg `foo-24`) and grant the Lambda function permission to access `foo-*`. You then won't have to modify the permissions each time. Or, since you're always adding permissions for every new bucket, just grant it access to every bucket in the first place and you won't have to modify the policy.

Comment: @jarmod , thanks for pointing out changed to IAM policy now

Answer (score 12):

I found the right way of doing it:

You have to create a policy version (including your policy changes) of your existing policy and tag it as default. As so the new version will replace the existing policy.

Get your existing policy :

```
policy = iam.Policy('arn:aws:iam::' + ACCOUNT_ID + ':policy/' + POLICY_NAME)
```

Get JSON from this policy:

```
policyJson = policy.default_version.document
```

Change it as you want:

```
policyJson['Statement'].append({  
'Action': '*',
'Resource': 'arn:aws:ec2:::*/*',
'Effect': 'Allow'
})
```

Create a policy version with the new JSON and the option **SetAsDefault** to True

```
response = client.create_policy_version(
    PolicyArn= 'arn:aws:iam::' + ACCOUNT_ID + ':policy/' + POLICY_NAME,
    PolicyDocument= json.dumps(policyJson),
    SetAsDefault= True
)
```

Delete the previous version (optional but recommanded max 5 versions ):

```
response = client.delete_policy_version(
    PolicyArn= 'arn:aws:iam::' + ACCOUNT_ID + ':policy/' + POLICY_NAME,
    VersionId= version.version_id
    )
```

And you're good to go!

Thomas.

Ref: [IAM DOC](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_policy_version)

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the IAM policy, then delete and finally create it again with modified JSON as it was previously suggested.

**Code Snippet**

```
import boto3, json

# Create IAM client
iam = boto3.resource('iam')

policy = iam.Policy('arn:aws:iam::ACCCOUNT_ID:policy/CustomS3Policy')
version = policy.default_version
policyJson = version.document
policyJson['Statement'][0]['Resource'].append('arn:aws:s3:::anotherbucket/*')

print(policyJson)

client = boto3.client('iam')
response = client.delete_policy(
    PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::ACCCOUNT_ID:policy/CustomS3Policy'
)
print(response)

response = client.create_policy(
  PolicyName='CustomS3Policy',
  PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policyJson)
)
print(response)
```

**References**:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/iam-example-policies.html
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.delete_policy
https://gist.github.com/alexcasalboni/07414d62290828ea03a14b4bf2157fd1